# Is it possible for Airflow scheduler to first finish the previous day's cycle before starting the next?

Tags: python, python-3.x, airflow, scheduler

Right now, nodes in my DAG proceeds to the next day's task before the rest of the nodes of that DAG finishes. Is there a way for it to wait for the rest of the DAG to finish before moving unto the next day's DAG cycle?

(I do have depends_on_past as true, but that does not work in this case)

My DAG looks like this:

```
               O
               l
               V
O -> O -> O -> O -> O
```

Also, tree view pic of the dag]

[image: tree view pic of the dag]

Answer (score 27):

Might be a bit late for this answer, but I ran into the same issue and the way I resolved it is I added two extra tasks in each dag. "Previous" at the start and "Complete" at the end. Previous task is external task sensor which monitors previous job. Complete is just a dummy operator. Lets say it runs every 30 minutes so the dag would look like this:

```
dag = DAG(dag_id='TEST_DAG', default_args=default_args, schedule_interval=timedelta(minutes=30))

PREVIOUS = ExternalTaskSensor(
    task_id='Previous_Run',
    external_dag_id='TEST_DAG',
    external_task_id='All_Tasks_Completed',
    allowed_states=['success'],
    execution_delta=timedelta(minutes=30),
    dag=DAG
)

T1 = BashOperator(
    task_id='TASK_01',
    bash_command='echo "Hello World from Task 1"',
    dag=dag
)

COMPLETE = DummyOperator(
    task_id='All_Tasks_Completed',
    dag=DAG
)

PREVIOUS >> T1 >> COMPLETE
```

So the next dag, even tho it will come into the queue, it will not let tasks run until PREVIOUS is completed.

Comment: Indeed, https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/airbnb_airflow/qh-2zXfTeqg

Comment: A few issues I ran into with this in case helpful for others - 1) make sure you're not using `SequentialExecutor` (the default) which is single-threaded. This will cause your second Sensor to run before your first real job, and you'll get in a deadlocked state with the task in queued state. 2) You may want to add `LatestOnlyOperator` to the beginning to skip backfilling 3) If you do that, you'll need to update `allowed_states` to include `"skipped"` status, 4) if you don't do that you'll need to manually mark the first task successful to get out of an initial deadlock situation.

Comment: You can set `wait_for_downstream=True` "when set to true, an instance of task X will wait for tasks immediately downstream of the previous instance of task X to finish successfully before it runs. This is useful if the different instances of a task X alter the same asset, and this asset is used by tasks downstream of task X. Note that depends_on_past is forced to True wherever wait_for_downstream is used." This works in airflow 1.9. https://airflow.apache.org/code.html

Comment: Another comment: I had to manually mark the first instance of the "Previous Run" task as successful. If not it would wait forever on a previous execution time that didn't exist.

Comment: @Cory can you please elaborate on "This will cause your second Sensor to run before your first real job"? By "second Sensor" do you mean second instance (second DAG run) of my "ExternalTaskSensor"? Why would this "second Sensor" run before my first real job? Why is the specific to `SequentialExecutor`?

Comment: @AbhilashKishore - sorry it's been a long time since I was working on this! I don't remember the details.

Comment: you can use sequentialExecutor, all you need to do is place max_active_runs=1 in the dag

Comment: Is there any workaround for manually marking the first task as success?

Answer (score 6):

What ended up working for me is a combination of

1. Adding task dependencies : wait_for_downstream=True, depends_on_past=True
2. Adding max_active_runs:1 to while creating the dag. I did try to add max_active_runs as a default argument, but that did not work.

Comment: Functionally, is this any different or any way better than the `ExternalTaskSensor` approach described by @Oleg Yamin below?

Comment: Can confirm 'max_active_runs':1 in default_arguments does not work. However, I did not need either of wait_for_downstream=True, depends_on_past=True to get it to work (Airflow 2.0.2)

Comment: Note: this isn't perfect and might depend on the structure of the dag. `Wait_for_downstream` only handles _direct_ downstream dependencies. If the prev dag execution failed on a _parallel_ task, it won't work as you might expect.

Comment: @Gebe Not able to get your statement "prev dag execution failed on a parallel task" - Could you please elaborate the DAG structure? Assume if I set the param wait_for_downstream and depends_on_past at first task of the DAG structure, I will not have issues, right?

Answer (score 4):

if you want to just run one instance at a time then try setting
max_active_runs=1

Comment: @nono If I were to guess (I didn't down vote it) it would be because that answer doesn't enforce ordering b

Comment: @nono I agree with joeb. In other words, by setting max_active_runs=1, there is no guarantee that the previous DAG instance finished successfully.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve the same without any additional tasks. The trick is `add a dependency from the 1st task to the last task and set wait_for_downstream=True for the 1st task`.

In that case, the 1st task of the next DAGrun will wait until the last task of the current run is complete. So the future DAGruns will be on hold. You can then set `max_active_runs=1` to limit such on-hold schedules.

A detailed example is given here [airflow-dag-past-run-sense](https://soyelherein.tech/blog/airflow-dag-past-run-sense.html)

Look at the dependencies.

```
with DAG('dag_past_run_sense',
         schedule_interval='*/2 * * * *',
         default_args=default_args,
         max_active_runs=1) as dag:

    read_incr_data = BashOperator(
        task_id='read_incr_data',
        wait_for_downstream=True,
        bash_command='date'
    )

    prepare_scd2 = BashOperator(
        task_id='prepare_scd2',
        bash_command='date'
    )

    load_final_table = PythonOperator(
        task_id="load_final_table",
        python_callable=load_final_table_status
    )

    read_incr_data >> prepare_scd2 >> load_final_table
    read_incr_data >> load_final_table
```

Comment: your answer is irrelevant to the question. question isnt about relationship between tasks but rather make a dag to look for its previous run.