# Airflow depends_on_past for whole DAG

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

Is there a way in airflow of using the `depends_on_past` for an entire DagRun, not just applied to a Task?

I have a daily DAG, and the Friday DagRun errored on the 4th task however the Saturday and Sunday DagRuns still ran as scheduled. Using `depends_on_past = True` would have paused the DagRun on the same 4th task, however the first 3 tasks would still have run.

I can see in the DagRun DB table there is a `state` column that contains `failed` for the Friday DagRun. What I want is a way configuring a DagRun to not start if the previous DagRun failed, not start and run until finding a Task that previously failed.

Does anyone know if this is possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible for Airflow scheduler to first finish the previous day's cycle before starting the next?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41009228/is-it-possible-for-airflow-scheduler-to-first-finish-the-previous-days-cycle-be)

Comment: @PriksoNAI and that question has a correct answer.

Answer (score 15):

At your first task, set `depends_on_past=True` and `wait_for_downstream=True`, the combination will result in that current dag-run runs only if the last run succeeded.

Because by setting the first task at current dag-run would waits for previous 
 (depends_on_past) and all tasks (wait_for_downstream) to succeed

Comment: depends_on_past is forced to True wherever wait_for_downstream is used.

Comment: This answer is wrong and does not do what Questioner asks. This answer is the correct for this problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42959225/3970469

Comment: Disagree with @PriksoNAI - the answer is correct. `wait_for_downstream` is a configuration that enhances `depends_on_past`. `depends_on_past` will just check the previous task (so in the example given, Steps 1-3 will still run on Saturday). `wait_for_downstream` takes that a step further and checks that all of the *previous run's* downstream tasks also succeeded. In the example given, this means Step 1 would not have run on Saturday, because Step 4 on Friday failed, which is downstream of Step 1 on Friday.

Comment: Agree with @PriksoNAI. I've just checked it. I set `depends_on_past` and `wait_for_downstream` to `True` on my DAG, and if I trigger it manually one by one two times, I see that the second instance does not wait for the first one success.

Comment: @Jacobian with `depends_on_past=True`, "the previous task instance needs to have succeeded (except if it is the first run for that task)". I think since both your instances are running in parallel, Airflow cannot determine which one is the first run. Maybe Airflow only checks for completed runs and not currently running ones while determining which is the first run and which is not. Maybe someone can confirm this.

Comment: This does not ensure that the previous run was successful it only checks if the previous DAG run completed.

Comment: @Tameem that's not correct, depends_on_past checks if the previous instance has succeeded or has been skipped not just completed. Actually that answer is not correct. wait_for_downstream only checks for immediately direct downstream tasks, so the first level of downstream tasks. Which mean, by setting depends_on_past to the first task, doesn't prevent you from running the next DAGRun if a failure happened in the last task of your DAG

Answer (score 7):

This question is a bit old but it turns out as a first google search result and the highest rated answer is clearly misleading (and it has made me struggle a bit) so it definitely demands a proper answer. Although the second rated answer should work, there's a *cleaner* way to do this and I personally find using xcom ugly.

The Airflow has a special operator class designed for monitoring status of tasks from other dag runs or other dags as a whole. So what we need to do is to add a task preceding all the tasks in our dag, checking if the previous run has succeded.

```
from airflow.sensors.external_task_sensor import ExternalTaskSensor


previous_dag_run_sensor = ExternalTaskSensor(
    task_id = 'previous_dag_run_sensor',
    dag = our_dag,
    external_dag_id = our_dag.dag_id,
    execution_delta = our_dag.schedule_interval
)

previous_dag_run_sensor.set_downstream(vertices_of_indegree_zero_from_our_dag)
```

Answer (score 5):

One possible solution would be to use `xcom`:

1. Add 2 PythonOperators `start_task` and `end_task` to the DAG.
2. Make all other tasks depend on `start_task`
3. Make `end_task` depend on all other tasks (`set_upstream`).
4. `end_task` will always push a variable `last_success = context['execution_date']` to xcom (`xcom_push`). (Requires `provide_context = True` in the PythonOperators).
5. And `start_task` will always check xcom (`xcom_pull`) to see whether there exists a `last_success` variable with value equal to the previous DagRun's execution_date or to the DAG's start_date (to let the process start).

Example use of xcom:
https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/master/airflow/example_dags/example_xcom.py

Answer (score 1):

Here a solution that addresses Marc Lamberti's concern, namely, that 'wait_for_download' is not "recursive".

The solution entails "embedding" your original DAG in between two dummy tasks, a *start_task* and an *end_task*.

Such that:

- The *start_task* precedes all your original *initial* tasks (ie, no other task in your DAG can start until *start_task* is completed).
- A *end_task* follows all your original *ending* tasks (ie, all branches in your DAG converge to that dummy *end_task*).
- *start_task* also *directly* precedes the *end_task*.

These conditions are provided by the following code:

```
start_task >> [_all_your_initial_tasks_here_]
[_all_your_ending_tasks_here] >> end_task
start_task >> end_task
```

Additionally, one needs to set that *start_task* has `depends_on_past=True` and `wait_for_downstream=True`

Comment: Great solution even if it's a bit hacky.