# Prevent Scheduler from starting overlapping task

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

`airflow.cfg`:

```
# airflow version = 1.10.1
executor = LocalExecutor
parallelism = 32
dag_concurrency = 16
```

And a dag.py:

```py
with DAG('mydag', schedule_interval="@hourly") as dag:
    # define tasks
```

But sometimes my task takes longer to finish than my `schedule_interval`, and airflow schedules the next task before the previous is done.

This is causing all sorts of awful race conditions.

Is there a way I can explicitly prevent overlapping tasks from being scheduled?  Even if that means skipping a run entirely?

Answer (score 2):

- I think what you are looking for is [`depends_on_past`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52835084/3679900) and [`wait_for_downstream`](https://airflow.apache.org/_api/airflow/operators/index.html#airflow.operators.BaseOperator) [params of `BaseOperator`](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/airflow/models/baseoperator.py#L107)
- Also check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49852833/3679900) handy explanation

---

**EDIT-1**

*updated as per [comment by **@Chengzhi**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57227444/prevent-scheduler-from-starting-overlapping-task#comment100969700_57229106)*

While above would likely solve your problems, if you wish to skip overlapping DagRuns entirely, use

- [`max_active_runs_per_dag`](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/v1-10-stable/airflow/config_templates/default_airflow.cfg#L136): global setting for all dags
- [`max_active_runs`](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/airflow/models/dag.py#L134): dag-level override-able setting

Comment: to add to @y2k-shubham point: max_active_runs_per_dag is the default for all dags, if you want to do it on specific dag, override it on DAG level (https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/v1-10-stable/airflow/models/dag.py#L140-L143) , also if you don't care too much about each dag_run, set `catchup` to False can avoid backpressure of each trigger.